# Sql query to split one column into two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have one single column as project name, the data in 
project name

```
1.1.1 chapter1
1.1.2 chapter2
```

I want to divide that single column into two columns as

```
Major   Minor
1.1     .1 chapter1
1.1     .2 chapter2
```

the datatype of my project name column is nvarchar,
I am using sql 2005

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
declare @x nvarchar(500) = '1.1.1 chapter1'

select substring(@x,1,charindex('.',@x,1+charindex('.',@x))-1) as Major,
       substring(@x,charindex('.',@x,1+charindex('.',@x)),len(@x)-charindex('.',@x,1+charindex('.',@x))) as Minor
```

Substitute @x in your query ..

and the fiddle for it : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/4424/0

updated with the . in front and proof to error

declare @x nvarchar(500) = '1.1.1 chapter1'

```
select @x,
   case when charindex('.',@x,1+charindex('.',@x)) <> 0 then substring(@x,1,charindex('.',@x,1+charindex('.',@x))-1)
        else 'Cannot be parsed'
   end,
   case when charindex('.',@x,1+charindex('.',@x)) <> 0 then substring(@x,charindex('.',@x,1+charindex('.',@x)),len(@x)-charindex('.',@x,1+charindex('.',@x))+1)
        else 'Cannot be parsed'
   end
```

and without the . in front

declare @x nvarchar(500) = '1.1.1 chapter1'

```
select @x,
   case when charindex('.',@x,1+charindex('.',@x)) <> 0 then substring(@x,1,charindex('.',@x,1+charindex('.',@x))-1)
        else 'Cannot be parsed'
   end,
   case when charindex('.',@x,1+charindex('.',@x)) <> 0 then substring(@x,1+charindex('.',@x,1+charindex('.',@x)),len(@x)-charindex('.',@x,1+charindex('.',@x)))
        else 'Cannot be parsed'
   end
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/4430/0

Comment: I got an error as "Invalid length parameter passed to the SUBSTRING function" this is ma query

Comment: If you pass instead of @x an varchar or nvarchar, it will work perfectly .. check the fiddle ..

Comment: i checked ur fiddle, its running f9, but on my sql server 2005 i am getting error

Comment: Show me the query you are using. The query should work fine on sql 2005. Unless not all your strings look like you showed. I did not do any error checking .. so it will give an error if your strings are different in your query .. (they need at list 2 points)

Comment: SELECT vProjectName, substring(vProjectName,1,charindex('.',vProjectName,charindex('.',vProjectName)+1)) as Major,
       substring(vProjectName,charindex('.',vProjectName,1+charindex('.',vProjectName)),len(vProjectName)-charindex('.',vProjectName,1+charindex('.',vProjectName))) as Minor

from projects

Comment: the above query works absolutely f9, the only problem is in Minor column i want "1 chapter i am human" but i am getting output as ".1 chapter i", i am not getting the whole syntax

Comment: thank you very much, it worked for me, now i only want to give alias name using as for both columns, but it is giving me error

Comment: put as minor, or as major immediately after the end

Answer (score 0):

```
select substring(ProjectName,1,charindex('.',ProjectName,charindex('.',@t)+1)) as Major
```